# How to run/execute/debug react/redux app from Intellij

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea

I have a simple `react/redux` app that I can run from the command line via `npm start`, and debug from the browser, but I would like to continue its development using `Intellij`. Unfortunately, the [snippets](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/react.html) of advice in don't provide enough overall context, given my level of web-development experience, to help very much. And I haven't been able to find a simple example application to use as a pattern to figure out the process.

**Principal question:** I can open the application directory structure in `Intellij`, see all the file of my little application, and build it without errors, so I need to create a run configuration. Which configuration template should I use, and to what do I set the associated parameters so I can run and debug it from `Intellij`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

The docs give enough information to start from... You need building and starting your application using `npm start` (can be done in IDEA by opening your app `package.json` in the editor and clicking the **Run** icon in the gutter to the left of your `start` script). Then you have to create a new **JavaScript debug** configuration: choose **Run | Edit Configurations**, click **Add** icon, and choose **JavaScript Debug** from the list. In the **URL** field, enter URL you normally use to open your app in browser (`http://localhost:3000/` or whatever it looks like). Click **Debug**

with your sample app:

- select **npm start** run configuration, press **Run**
- select **Debug Application** configuration, press **Debug**:

[image]

See https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/guide/tutorials/react_typescript_tdd/chrome_debugging/

Comment: Thank you - some progress. I now have a configuration for nom, and one for my app that look like the screen shots in the reference you supplied.

Comment: However, the breakpoint in my react code doesn't seem to be hit, although my Chrome browser page opens and my app is running and working.

I haven't explicitly done anything to install/configure web storm/webpack. The only two web storm-related plug-ins available in the marketplace didn't seem applicable.

Console shows messages that debuggers are listening.

The posting didn't seem to indicate that I need to do something to configure my Chrome browser, but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: this should work out of the box with the apps created by create-react-app, no special steps required. Please share a project the issue can be reproduced with + screencast that shows your steps

Comment: Installed Webstorm 2019.3, 'new project' to select 'React App', named it 'debugtest'; 'Debug Application' cfg -set 'Remote URL' for 'src' to 'webpack:///src'  per instructions.

Brkpt on line 7, `return` in the `render()`, of App.js.

Selected 'npm start' cnfig, clicked 'debug' icon.

Console says dbgr is listening, simple default page showsw in the browser, but brkpt not hit.

Project in Box: https://app.box.com/s/ycgea1f4uid90vm5u1k2s3ug5xo851l1

BTW, the video recommended in the 2nd paragraph of the referenced link says it's private.  Any other way to view that video?

Thanks!

Comment: please try following the instructions... There is normally no need in specifying 'Remote URL' unless you are using Webstorm < 2017.x, and it's **JavaScript debug** configuration and NOT 'npm start' that you need to debug... P.S. when sharing projects, please make sure to delete `node_modules` folder to reduce the package size.

Comment: OK - that worked... thanks very much. Now to see if I can extrapolate that to my own project. But last question: should I be able to do the same with IntelliJ, or if I want to debug into JS, I'll have to use WebStorm?  Thanks again.

Comment: This works but is there a way to see network requests and responses? I don't see any way to do that. Until then it's just better to stick to Google Chrome or any other browser for debugging.

Comment: updated Link https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/guide/tutorials/react_typescript_tdd/chrome_debugging/

Answer (score 4):

I found the simplest way the achieve all the above without hustle. Open Terminal on Webstorm and start your app normally using npm start as shown below.

```
npm start
```

[image]

Click on the link while pressing cmd + shift on Mac, on Windows or Linux use Ctrl + Shift and a click. This will open debug sessions and all your break points will be observed

Answer (score 2):

I found two ways to run React-app in Intellij Idea but it has two different drawbacks:

- in 1st scenario Idea doesnt work as debugger
- 2nd we need to run 'npm start' manually. If we need to rerun 'npm start' we need to stop it. The port will be still in use and we shall to specify the new port in the configs and in npm start another port from the start to successfully use it as debugger;

## Let's configure react-app from the scratch:

```
1. add new configuration: JavaScript Debug
name: react-app
URL: http://192.168.1.106:3000/
Browser: Chrome
```

[image: new configuration: JavaScript Debug]

```
Script before launch: Run npm script [reactapp-directory/package.json]
|- package.json: ..../reactapp-directory/package.json
|- Command: start
|- Node interpreter: Project node(/usr/bin/node) 10.19.0
|- Package manager: Project node(/usr/bin/npm 6.14.4
```

[image: javascript debug configuration]

Save changes
2. Open your script and add debug breakpoint
3. and click 'debug' button.

## What we expect but dont achieve:

(I've already placed the [issue-ticket in the jetbrains support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/3293378?page=1)
Idea):

1. Idea successfully runs the app with set npm start
2. opens browser new tab with specified url http://192.168.1.106:3000/
3. stops on the breakpoint

## What happens exactly, there are **two different scenarios**:

**1st**: It performs first two steps (

- 1. successfully runs the app with set npm start
- 2. opens browser new tab with specified url http://192.168.1.106:3000/

) but doesnt work as debugger so we need to use browser DevTool to debug

**2nd**: To make it work the build-in debugger you should to change the run steps:

- 1. run 'npm start' from the shell by yourself

[image]

- 2. click 'debug' with the set configuration
- 3. remove from the config the ***Script before launch***

[image: how to remove script before launch in idea]

or

run see the running script clashes with previous npm start one and you need to refuse it by pushing button 'n';

[image]

- 4. Idea opens new tab with specified url and successfully stops on the chosen debugging point